# How to solve this equation by Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have an equation to be solved. But Mathematica does not work for it. I hope the solution x can be expressed as a function of a and b

`Solve[(x/Sin[a])^2 == ((1 - x)/Sin[b])^2 + 
   1 + (x/Tan[a] - (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2 - 
   2 ((1 - x)/Sin[b]) Sqrt[1 + (x/Tan[a] - (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2]
     Sin[b - ArcTan[x/Tan[a] - (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b]]], x]`

By using $x = \frac{y}{l}$, the above equation is reduced from the following one:

`Solve[(y/Sin[a])^2 == ((l - y)/Sin[b])^2 + 
   l^2 + (y/Tan[a] - (l - y)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2 - 
   2 ((l - y)/Sin[b]) Sqrt[l^2 + (y/Tan[a] - (l - y)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2]
     Sin[b - ArcTan[(y/Tan[a] - (l - y)/Sin[b] Cos[b])/l]], y]`

If the reduced equation can be simplified to zero, how about this original one? I cannot simplify the original one to zero. From this original equation, can we get y as a function of l, a and b?

Comment: Mathematica solves your equation and gives `{}`: no solution!

Comment: Yes, why is there no solution? In principle, there should be a solution x as a function of a and b. I do not know why Mathematica gives { }.

Comment: `Solve` probably fails to get a "proper" simplification. It is actually tautologically true (that is, for all values of `x`).

Answer (score 1):

Your equation does not contain any information:

```
(x/Sin[a])^2 == ((1 - x)/Sin[b])^2 + 1 + (x/Tan[a] - (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2 -
  2 ((1 - x)/Sin[b]) Sqrt[1 + (x/Tan[a] -
  (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b])^2] Sin[b - ArcTan[x/Tan[a] -
  (1 - x)/Sin[b] Cos[b]]] // FullSimplify
```

> True

Comment: Thank you! How about the original one? In terms of your answer, I modify my post.

Comment: If you replace Solve with FullSimplify in the original one it also gives True, though you need to add the assumption that l > 0.